# How to Bind a Value of a Dictionary to a SwiftUI Control?

Tags: swift, list, dictionary, binding, swiftui

I have a `class DataPoint` which is the value of a dictionary.

`DataPoint` has a member variable `value` that I need to bind to a `Slider` in SwiftUI.

I provide the data `class AppData` as `@Environment Object` to SwiftUI, the dictionary holds the instances of `class DataPoint`.

I fail to manage to bind the `DataPoint.value` member variable to the SwiftUI `Slider` value.

These are the relevant code snippets.

The @Published data:

```
class AppData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataPoints: [UUID : DataPoint] = [:] {
    ...
}
```

The data structure:

```
class DataPoint: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: Double
}
```

The SwiftUI view of DataPoints `AppDataList`:

```
struct AppDataList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(Array(appData.dataPoints.values)) { dataPoint in
                NavigationLink(destination: DataPointDetail(dataPointID: dataPoint.id)) {
                    Text("\(dataPoint.value)")
                }
            }
    ...
}
```

The SwiftUI `DataPointDetail` view that I struggle with, it is referenced from `AppDataList`:

```
struct DataPointDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData
    var dataPointID: UUID

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Data Point Detail")
                Text("\(appData.dataPoints[dataPointID]!.value)")
/* This line */
/* troubles  */
/* me!       */
/*  --->     */ Slider(value: appData.dataPoints[dataPointID]?.value, in: 0...10000)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(appData.dataPoints[dataPointID]!.id)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The root content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if appData.dataPoints.count > 0 {
                AppDataList()
            } else {
                NoDataPoints()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The creation of the root content view in SceneDelegate:

```
        let contentView = ContentView()
            .environmentObject(appData)
```

I get an error in the editor: `Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'` and it is in the line of VStack in DataPointDetail view. I believe that it has got nothing to do with the VStack.

[image: Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment']

Commenting out the `Slider` line produces compilable and runnable code.

How would one accomplish this?

Comment: do you receive any compiler error?

Comment: I get an error in the editor: `Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'` and it is in the line of `VStack` in `DataPointDetail` view. I believe that it has got nothing to do with the `VStack`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most quick solution is to use wrapper binding, as in below snapshot

```swift
Slider(value: Binding<Double>(
    get: { self.appData.dataPoints[self.dataPointID]?.value ?? 0 },
    set: { self.appData.dataPoints[self.dataPointID]?.value = $0}), in: 0...10000)
```

Comment: I thank you, Asperi. The editor shows no errors and the code compiles and runs. The problem still lingering is that the value does not change. I can move the slide but the value remains until I add another `DataPoint` to the list.

Comment: @JackB.Erger I would make model as `struct DataPoint`